# Java Selenium - ChromeDriver not following URL arguments?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am stumped. I am trying to automate some testing. One step is to click on a link in an email to verify the user. The link look something like this:

```
https://www.mailinator.com/key/url?url=https%3A//destination-website.com/verifytokenhere104981309blablablah
```

where Mailinator is the site for the user's email address. I can automate clicking on the link, but when it is clicked, it only opens mailinator and doesn't ever go to the final website.

Is there Chrome option that I can set to allow the link to be fully followed? Thanks for the help!

Comment: i think this is because of session and its unique to each session

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So, would I have to create a new session to use that URL? I don't think I know how to do that. It's interesting that this is only happening while running the test in selenium. Manually clicking on the link works just fine.

Comment: You can extract the link as a String, remove the mailinator part and navigate driver to the desired url.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually what I ended up doing to make it work.